# Qual è il significato di "gli s'era fatto grazia del passato"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Ah, e sai chi è un altro? Carlino. Anche lui, sempre con l'“Uomo Qualunque” in tasca... Ricordatene, Mara: se si azzarda a venir qui, sbattigli la porta in faccia. Io tipi come lui non ce li voglio per casa. Razza di mascalzone! Dopo che **gli s'era fatto grazia del passato**...

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "gli s'era fatto grazia del passato" in questo brano. Alla [voce "grazia" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/grazia/) ho trovato

> *fare grazia di una cosa*, dispensare da un obbligo, da una seccatura o sim.

Tuttavia, continuo a non capire la frase del brano sopra citato. Significa che gli si era perdonato il passato?

Dovete sapere che la vicenda narrata nel libro accade giusto dopo la liberazione d'Italia in seguito alla Seconda guerra mondiale.

Comment: > Significa che gli si era perdonato il passato? Esattamente

Comment: Dovresti usare *continuo a non capire* e non *continuo senza capire*. Te lo dico solo perché hai un ottimo italiano e credo ti interessino suggerimenti per perfezionarlo.

Comment: @N74: Grazie mille! Faccio la correzione.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Fare o concedere  la [grazia](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/grazia.php)*** è un'espressione che originariamente si usava in riferimento al potere assoluto dei Re o dei Papi, nel perdonare e quindi risparmiare la vita dei condannati a morte. Attualmente si usa in riferimento ai Capi di Stato o agli alti prelati più col significato di perdonare delle colpe gravi.

> - Atto di generosità, di pietà, di condiscendenza: concedere la grazia.
> - *Fare grazia, risparmiare la vita a un vinto*
> - Fare grazia a qualcuno di qualcosa, *sollevarlo da un incarico gravoso, esonararlo.*

- Fare grazia del passato significa perdonare le colpe commesse in passato (non conosco il contesto, ma potrebbe essere usato anche in senso figurato).